# Export Wordpress Search & Filter Pro result to excel (Front End)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, export-to-excel, elementor

I want to export a Wordpress frontend search result to Excel file.

I have created a data management site using Wordpress, and used those plugins:

- Custom Post Type (CPT UI): to have a dedicated section for post management
- Advanced Custom Field (ACF): to enter data forms, attached to that post
- Search & Filter Pro: to filter search result, based on above ACF form values.
- Elementor Pro: to display "frontend search result", using Loop Template and Search & Filter shortcode.

Is there anyway user can export this Frontend Search Result to an EXCEL file, for download?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start this off in a direction, and we can refine it together, if needed.

You can easily create a CSV file (which users can open with Excel):

```
$array = [ ["letters","numbers"], ["a",3], ["b",4] ];

/* Could be $_POST or something else */
function create_csv( $array ) {

    /* Container */
    $output = ''; 

    foreach( $array as $data ){
        $count = count($data); $c=0;
        foreach( $data as $d ){
            $c++;
            $output .= $d;
            if( $c !== $count ) { 
                $output .= ','; /* cell break */
            } else { 
                $output .= '\n'; /* row break */
            }
        }
    }       

    /* Build form array */
    $array = array(
        'array' => $output,
    );

    /* check if the file exists or not to determine if headers are needed */
    $headersNeeded = !file_exists('filename.csv');

    /* Open or Create CSV File */
    $fh = fopen('filename.csv', 'a');

    /* if headers are needed, add them */
    if ($headersNeeded){
        fputcsv($fh, $headers);
    }

    /* Populate the array */
    fputcsv($fh,$array);

    /* Close the file */
    fclose($fh);

}
```

If you can identify a way to 'read' the search results into such a function, and you design a method for identifying the unique file name on page render, you could use HTML5 button attributes to trigger the download:

```
 <a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply James. Yes .CSV is ok. I will try this out.